# "DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found" when trying to import pygame

Tags: python, pygame, python-3.6

I want to import pygame successfully, but this problem arises. I tried re-installing 'pygame' but it's not working (Windows 7 64 bit).

```
import pygame
```

I expect that the import error should not arise, but it shows

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "D:\IP\Snake Game PYTHON\SnakePython\Food.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pygame   File "C:\Users\WELCOME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pygame\__init__.py", line 127, in <module>
    from pygame.base import * ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you haven't installed the library properly. Navigate to your python install directory and in the `Scripts` folder, shift+right click and open CMD in the directory.
In the command line write:
`pip3 install pygame`
That should install the library i think.

Comment: I tried this, but it shows 'You are using pip version 9.0.3, however version 19.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.'...But when I type the advised command(in cmd), it shows me some error....'install' is not registered....what am I supposed to do now?? I am a beginner ... please help me out!!

Comment: @pystalker try running ```pip3 install pip3``` in the same directory. If that doesn't work, run ```python -m pip install --upgrade pip``` in your main python installation directory( where the python.exe file is ). If that doesn't work, reinstall python to the latest version from the website. Then try to install ```pygame``` again with the method above.